# XNA Game Studio 3D model editor suggestions

Tags: 3d, xna, modeling

I want to create basic low-poly 3D models to use in XNA Game Studio games. What cheap/free tools do people recommend?

And does anyone have any links or snippets of code that show how to load 3D models of some sort into XNA and then draw them on the screen?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at trueSpace also, its just become free - but as Evil Activity stated; Blender is also a good sugestion i just never really got use to its interface and how to do stuff. trueSpace is a little more easy in that way, but i think that blender is more powerful.

I guess you know http://creators.xna.com/, there is a 3D tutorial you can look at here:
http://creators.xna.com/en-US/education/gettingstarted

Answer (score 5):

[Blender](http://www.blender.org/) is a free 3D modeling tool. Here is an article covering from installation of blender, exporting, to the importing of a model made in Blender into the XNA enviroment:

[Getting started with Blender 3D and XNA](http://www.virtualrealm.com.au/blogs/getting-started-with-blender-3d-and-xna/)

Answer (score 1):

Ill second Blender.

You can find some handy tutorials linking XNA and Blender here;
http://www.stromcode.com/

Answer (score 1):

yes, truespace is a good choice. It's the first 3d authoring program I ever used. It's pretty simple, and it's free. you can find tutorials on the official website http://www.caligari.com/

If you don't plan on selling your game, you can download 3D Studio MAX student license. It's the full program for 3 years for free. The learning curve is pretty easy too, especially for modeling. You can find good tutorials on [digital tutors](http://www.digitaltutors.com/training/3ds_max-tutorials). some are free, some are not. There's also 3Dbuzz you can check out for tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

Having worked a modeler and texture artist for over 3 years, I have tried the majority of modeling tools and keep coming back to [Nevercenter's Silo](http://www.nevercenter.com/). It's the most elegant, well designed sub-d polygonal modeling application I have ever had the pleasure of using. Once you've used Silo, you'll wonder why anyone uses anything else.

Answer (score 0):

[Houdini](http://www.sidefx.com/). It have too a free tool, [Apprentice](http://www.sidefx.com/index.php?option=com_download&Itemid=208&task=apprentice).